# Discover a version of a WAR from the Maven pom.properties within common library code

Tags: java, maven, war

I have a shared library to reduce code duplication. As such, it doesn't know the group or artifact name of the web app it is part of, but I would like to provide a method to access the name and the version of the current WAR, like this

```
someCommonService.getAppDescriptor(); //returns "com.my.group:my-artefact"
someCommonService.getVersion(); //returns "1.2.3-SNAPSHOT"
```

Below is what I tried.

Both, Jetty and Tomcat (and most other web containers) allow to read the resource

`/META-INF/maven/com.my.group/my-artefact/pom.properties`

that contains the required information. All WAR files in the ecosystem of concern have this file.

But you would need to know the group and artifact beforehand, which is an extra hurdle/step to specify to use in such a common library.

One could technically "discover" the correct root by going through this enumeration:

`Enumeration<URL> en = getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF");`

and eliminating everything with `.jar!` on the path. But how would one then discover the group and artifact (i.e. list the sub-directories?)

Maybe there is a better way to achieve the same goal (without changing app's project POMs or building steps)?

UPDATE 
The only workable solution is to make Maven Archiver update manifest with implementation and specification entries [as per Maven spec](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifest.html). It has drawbacks (bloating poms, mostly) and does not answer the question. It seems either Java resource loading API or Maven dropped the ball here.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://blog.soebes.de/blog/2014/01/02/version-information-into-your-appas-with-maven/

Comment: @khmarbaise It's a nice summary, thanks! None of the approaches answer the question (make library reliably discover group, artifact and version ), but it helps to come up with some interim solution.

Comment: If a library should give this information itself it must offer an Java class/interface which can be asked for such information which you can implement by using the templates-maven-plugin.